# "pelo andar da carruagem..." When and where did this saying originate?

Tags: expressões

To be honest, in my lifetime I've seen closed carriages only in films and museums, which  makes me suppose this expression was coined very long ago. Was it a foreign expression (French, for instance) which somebody translated into pt-PT and was brought to Brazil by the Portuguese?  Is it a genuine Portuguese saying? Or is it just a Brazilian expression?  Can you think of any contemporary expression in Portuguese having the same meaning?

"pelo andar da carruagem" translates as "the way things are going..."

Comment: Esta expressão ainda se usa (vi um manual de redação que diz pra não usar, lol), então, ela pode ser substituída pelo seu significado: "pela maneira como os fatos estão se desenrolando", "do jeito que as coisas vão (acontecendo)", "pelo jeito" [várias expressões](http://detudoblogue.blogspot.com.br/2012/02/expressoes-idiomaticas-brasileiras.html)

Comment: @AndréLyra    "pelo jeito" conveys exactly the same.  I like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to several sites (e.g., [this](https://www.portaldaliteratura.com/proverbios.php?id=525) and [this](https://proverbios-populares.com/pelo-andar-da-carruagem-ve-se-logo-quem.html)) it's part of a proverb:

> Pelo andar da carruagem se vê quem vai de viagem. *or*
>
> Pelo andar da carruagem se vê quem vem nela.

And I find no reputable source, but [this site](http://www.geografia-ensino.com/2014/06/proverbios-populares-de-portugal.html) and [this paper](http://publicacoes.fatea.br/index.php/eccom/article/viewFile/439/288) claim that this proverb is of Portuguese origin.

A more common expression with the same meaning is "Pelo jeito [que as coisas vão]."